# Deleting generalised strings from a text file

Tags: python

I am trying to delete strings from a text file.  The strings consist of different types of characters and are all different, but they all start with the same three letters and finish at the end of the line.

So far I am using this code, which I know works when I want to delete all occurrences of a specific string:

```
import sys
import fileinput

for i, line in enumerate(fileinput.input('duck_test.txt', inplace=1)):
    sys.stdout.write(line.replace('pep.*', '')
```

I have tried to adapt it to delete a generalised string using '.*' but it doesn't work.  Does anyone know where I am going wrong?  Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at regular expressions? Python has the builtin `re` module for using regular expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following tested code will replace all strings that begin with the letters 'pep' and end with a newline in the file 'duck_test' with an empty string:

```
import sys
import fileinput
import re

for i, line in enumerate(fileinput.input('duck_test', inplace=1)):
    sys.stdout.write(re.sub(r'pep.*', '', line))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [`re`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) module for that purpose:

```
import re
import fileinput


for line in fileinput.input('duck_test.txt', inplace=True):
    if not re.search(r'pep.*', line):
        sys.stdout.write(line)
```

Comment: Hi Xi, thanks for that!  There is still a slight problem though.  This code deletes the entire line that contains the string that begins 'pep', but I need to keep the string at the beginning of the line, and just delete from 'pep' onwards.  I've been trying to figure out how to do this but keep getting stuck.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Don't worry, I've figured it out!